# iOS ARKit state (cameraDidChangeTrackingState) stuck in initializing, doesn't track

Tags: ios, arkit

Apologies for the newb question in advance (can't find it elsewhere on SO), but has anyone had problems in getting any and/or all the ARKit demos to initialize?

Take for example, the default / vanilla app - what you get when you create an empty ARKit project. What I see is the ship hovering above the default view port, and when I pan, it stays pretty much centered in the viewport and not fixed in space, I cannot move above or to the sides of the spaceship.  When I look at the camera state property in cameraDidChangeTrackingState, it shows "limited / initializing, but never changes from that.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious, like perhaps an entitlement - or some other device level setting?

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, cameraDidChangeTrackingState camera: ARCamera) {
    switch camera.trackingState {
    case .notAvailable:
        print("Tracking: not available: \(camera.trackingState)")
    case .limited(let reason):
        print("Tracking limited: \(reason)") <-- only gets here, with "initializing"
    case .normal:
        print("tracking normal: \(camera.trackingState)")
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, I am using Xcode 9.0, and an iPhone 8.

Thanks!

Comment: What reason does the method print?

Comment: It reported "initializing", perhaps I should have been more explicit in the body of the post.  Per my answer below, the problem went away after restarting the device.

Answer (score 4):

As odd as it seemed, simply restarting the phone fixed the problems on all the apps that I was seeing.  I have no idea what went wrong or why though.

Comment: Alright, that was really a weird issue, but you got it fixed after all!

Comment: For what it is worth I had a similar thing happen and the solution was the same.  It never transitioned to normal tracking.  Maybe this is something they will fix but it would be a good idea to monitor the time and notify what is going on.

Comment: I think you can validate your answer since it still worked for me today on ios 14.2, iPhone SE :)

Answer (score 0):

You got to add the following lines of code into `viewDidLoad()`

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

This will then allow the ARKit scene to start tracking surfaces.

Comment: I wish that were it, but it didn't change anything.  Thanks though.